# @PreAuthorize on a nested method in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have spring bean in which I have two methods

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public void update(Person person) {  
   if(person.isActive())
      changeData(person);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#person,CHANGE_PERSON_FULL)")
public void changeData(Person person) {
...
}
```

I have added my custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. I have setup `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)`. Everything works ok when annotation `@PreAuthorize` is above `update(Person person)`. I need to perform PreAuthorize on changeData. Is it something related to proxy? Do I need to create seperate bean with method changeData? Is it possible to force spring to check security on nested method?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `changeData()` directly from `update()`, you are not going through a proxy. Only proxy calls are enhanced with annotated behavior.

You could move that method to another bean, but you could also call it in the same bean but through a proxy using something like this:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public void update(Person person) {  
   if(person.isActive()) {
      context.getBean(MyBean.class).changeData(person);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `@PreFilter` annotation when you call update method which will also eliminate usage of `if` statement.

Something like this should work:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PreFilter("hasPermission(#person, CHANGE_PERSON_FULL) and hasPermission(#person.active == true)")
public void update(Person person) { 
      changeData(person);
}
```

Note, if you have extra code that needs to be executed after call to `changeData(...)` this approach may not be suitable for you.