# Using @PreAuthorize annotation on a method within a controller’s method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web-application based on Spring WebMVC and Spring Security. I want to use @PreAuthorize annotation with SpEL on a method within of a method in a @Controller class. Something like that:

```
@GetMapping(value= "/method")
public String exampleForMethodPreAuthorize() {
    if(methodController()){
        return "forMethodPreAuthorize";
    }
    else return null;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public final boolean methodController(){
    return true;
}
```

But it don't work. The method methodController() is invoked for all users, even if one no ADMIN. But nevertheless that code work correctly and method is able for Admin only:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")    
@GetMapping(value= "/method")
public String exampleForMethodPreAuthorize() {

    return "forMethodPreAuthorize";       
}
```

I don't understand because of what a mistake is? Ultimately I use component scan for searching controller-class and definition

```
security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
```

in ServletContext xml configuration.

Comment: Try to debug and see if hasRole() is invoked properly. It is in the class org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call methodController() directly from exampleForMethodPreAuthorize(), the call if not invoked through a proxy. Only proxy calls are enhanced with annotated behaviour.

Credits to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28168213/1849366. It also suggests two workarounds.

**Option 1:** Moving methodController() method to another bean.

**Option 2:** Call the method methodController() through a proxy using as follows.

```
@GetMapping(value= "/method")
public String exampleForMethodPreAuthorize() {
    if(context.getBean(MyController.class).methodController()){
        return "forMethodPreAuthorize";
    }
    else return null;
}
```